# Вывод в файл исключения

Tags: linux, исключения, jdbc, java, sql

Есть блок кода

```
catch (SQLException e) 
{
    System.out.println("Connection Failed! Check output console");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Каким образои вывести в файл результат выполения оператора

```
e.printStackTrace();
```

?

Answer (score 3):

Как то так:

```
e.printStackTrace(new PrintStream(new File("myfile.txt")));
```

Answer (score 2):

1. хороший вариант - log4j
2. самый обычный вариант - написать свой лог (создать файл и писать в него через стрим)

Comment: @Gorets помогите пожалуйста. log4j cсложный вариант для hadoop. Можете привести код пожалуйста (я совсем не понимаю как реализовать второй вавариант)?

Comment: @ivan89, log4j тоже от апача. Не думаю, что  сложно подружить.

Comment: В инете полно примеров сопряжения log4j и hadoop